# How to break text inside a parent div with white-space:nowrap in CSS?

Tags: css

I am struggling to break the text inside a parent div with `white-space:nowrap`. The property `word-wrap:break-word` for anchor is not working. I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinsharma1507/aqcdy0qp/1/).

Comment: Why mix a `white-space` setting with a `word-wrap` setting? Why not just use `white-space:normal`: https://jsfiddle.net/aqcdy0qp/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add a different white-space rule for your div a block.

Example:

```
#viewed_products div a {
    white-space: normal;
}
```